# how to make a simple collision detection of bitmaps in Android

Tags: android, collision-detection, android-canvas, bitmapfactory

I already have a code with collision but it has check for winners and ontouch method that I don't really need because my bitmaps are moving itself and I just want them to collide if they overlap.

```
private boolean checkCollision(Grafika first, Grafika second) {
        boolean retValue = false;

        int width = first.getBitmap().getWidth();
        int height = first.getBitmap().getHeight();

        int x1start = first.getCoordinates().getX();

        int x1end = x1start + width;

        int y1start = first.getCoordinates().getY();

        int y1end = y1start + height;

        int x2start = second.getCoordinates().getX();

        int x2end = x2start + width;

        int y2start = second.getCoordinates().getY();

        int y2end = y2start + height;

        if ((x2start >= x1start && x2start <= x1end) || (x2end >= x1start && x2end <= x1end)) {


            if ((y2start >= y1start && y2start <= y1end) || (y2end >= y1start && y2end <= y1end)) {
                retValue = true;
            }
        }
        return retValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to find whether or not 2 given rectangles somehow intersect (and therefore collide), here's the simplest check (C code; feel free to use floating-point values):

```
int RectsIntersect(int AMinX, int AMinY, int AMaxX, int AMaxY,
               int BMinX, int BMinY, int BMaxX, int BMaxY)
{
assert(AMinX < AMaxX);
assert(AMinY < AMaxY);
assert(BMinX < BMaxX);
assert(BMinY < BMaxY);

if ((AMaxX < BMinX) || // A is to the left of B
    (BMaxX < AMinX) || // B is to the left of A
    (AMaxY < BMinY) || // A is above B
    (BMaxY < AMinY))   // B is above A
{
    return 0; // A and B don't intersect
}

return 1; // A and B intersect
}
```

The rectangles A and B are defined by the minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates of their corners.

Comment: I have seen this answer before isn't what I needed because I don't use rects  but bitmaps and this assert isn't familiar to me